# Current status of HorizontalPodAutoscaling on Amazon EKS

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes

[Previously asked question](https://serverfault.com/questions/917831/horizontalpodautoscaling-on-amazon-eks#918535?newreg=5283b95b5ac74ef38ad93c4aa326a787)

I am also using EKS and wanted to know if yet they have solved this or is there a way around without using kops. Unable to comment on the same question because of low credits, hence posting this as a new question.

Comment: maybe you should comment to the other question if you want to see if there was an update?

Comment: Minimum credits required to comment is not satisfied, hence the new question

Comment: Sorry forgot about this one. Can you alter the question with this info, so I can undo the downvote?

Comment: I have made the required edit

Comment: Check this out as a workaround until amazon fixes eks https://medium.com/eks-hpa-workaround/k8s-hpa-controller-6ac2dfb4c028

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Kops is better suited than EKS since there is no way to configure kube config in EKS for the horizontal pod autoscalar default time and even the metric collection does not work by default. I used both of them and it looks like EKS does not provide any additional value over kops for aws.